# How To Know Where Java Scanner Delimiter Left Off?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Let's say I am examining this string char by char: **Jason Derulo "In My Head" charted.**

I use the Scanner Delimiter to extract **In My Head** (surrounded by double quotes).

Is there an easy way to get the location of where the Delimiter left off?

In other words, I want to easily know that the last place I left off is the char at my string.charat(25), the 25th char in my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner` does not come with this functionality.

You could add the length of the String to some `int` var, then use that to check the last letter handled:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int tracker = 0;

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    builder.append(next);
    tracker += next.length();

    System.out.println("The last letter handled was "+ builder.chatAt(tracker - 1));
}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder.length()` tells you how much has been put in it without a separate variable, 
but this is not the same as the amount of input consumed. If the input is `"....X.....Y"` where the dots are spaces, after two tokens 
the input has consumed 10 characters but only 2 have been put in `builder`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `StringBuilder#length()` is not used here